# jQuery mobile - after browser refresh page totally messed up

Tags: spring, jquery-mobile, spring-mobile

I'm developping a jqm application with spring mobile in the back-end.
Whenever I hit the browser refresh button on my mobile phone the page is completely devastated afterwards. Browsers back-button works properly.

The data are still available due prg pattern (flashAttributes in Spring) after refresh. Only the view is malformed.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: try changing the position where you included javascript(s)

Comment: The first jsp has a well-formated html5 structure with header and body and all the other jsps requested are defined jqm pages separared in extra files. That means all java scripts are loaded at the beginning on the first jsp when user requests my webapp. This page can also be refreshed without view errors. Unfortunately the others break down. I don't know where to place the javascripts.

Comment: added an answer. please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`jQuery Mobile` docs](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) :

> The simplest approach when building a jQuery Mobile site is to reference the same set of stylesheets and scripts in the head of every page. If you need to load in specific scripts or styles for a particular page, we recommend binding logic to the pageinit event (details below) to run necessary code when a specific page is created (which can be determined by its id attribute, or a number of other ways). Following this approach will ensure that the code executes if the page is loaded directly or is pulled in and shown via Ajax

So what happens is - in `jQuery Mobile`, the scripts and styles defined in the head are loaded only once. So, in normal conditions, it works fine, as all the pages will use the scripts loaded from the first page.

**But**. When you refresh a page in-between, it triggers a page-reload instead of the ajax navigation model thatjqm uses. So all the scripts and styles loaded from the first page will not be included from here on out.

What you need to do is "*reference the same set of stylesheets and scripts in the head of every page*", so that even if you hit refresh in the middle, the scripts and styles that had been loaded from the head of the first page are loaded again.

I recommend you read the docs from the above link fully to gain a better understanding.

Comment: Yes, you're right. That solved the problem. Now my application is stable.